# netplan bridge: no connection to/from virtual machine

Tags: networking, 18.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, netplan

I'd like to setup a brigde on my host (Ubuntu 18.04 server) to get a connection to the internet from/to my virtual machine (also Ubuntu 18.04 server), both with netplan. The host is a dedicated machine at Hetzner. Constellation at Hetzer:

**Host:**

- IP: 94.130.131.162
- Netmask: 255.255.255.192
- Gateway: 94.130.131.129
- Broadcast: 94.130.131.191

**Virtual machine** (separate IP and MAC):

- IP: 94.130.131.132
- Gateway: 94.130.131.129
- Broadcast: 94.130.131.191
- Separate MAC: 00:50:56:00:20:B9

My `/etc/netplan/50-bridge.yaml` at my host:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp0s31f6]
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [94.130.131.162/26]
      gateway4: 94.130.131.129
      nameservers:
          addresses: [213.133.98.98,213.133.99.99]
      dhcp6: no
```

My `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` at my virtual machine:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      addresses:
        - 94.130.131.132/26
      dhcp4: no
      gateway4: 94.130.131.129
      nameservers:
        addresses: [213.133.98.98,213.133.99.99]
```

At the virtual machine I can't get any connection to the internet :-(

`networkctl status -a` on the host:

```
● 1: lo
       Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: n/a
            Type: loopback
           State: carrier (unmanaged)
         Address: 127.0.0.1
                  ::1

● 2: enp0s31f6
       Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: /etc/systemd/network/10-enp0s31f6.network
            Type: ether
           State: routable (configured)
            Path: pci-0000:00:1f.6
          Driver: e1000e
          Vendor: Intel Corporation
           Model: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
      HW Address: 90:1b:0e:e0:d5:eb (Fujitsu Technology Solutions GmbH)
         Address: 94.130.131.162
                  2a01:4f8:13b:385d::2
                  fe80::921b:eff:fee0:d5eb
         Gateway: 94.130.131.129 (Juniper Networks)
                  fe80::1 (Juniper Networks)

● 3: br0
       Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-br0.network
            Type: ether
           State: routable (configured)
          Driver: bridge
      HW Address: 4e:7e:7e:53:85:b2
         Address: 94.130.131.162
                  fe80::4c7e:7eff:fe53:85b2
         Gateway: 94.130.131.129
             DNS: 213.133.98.98
                  213.133.99.99

● 4: vnet0
       Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: n/a
            Type: ether
           State: degraded (unmanaged)
          Driver: tun
      HW Address: fe:50:56:00:20:b9
         Address: fe80::fc50:56ff:fe00:20b9
```

At the `/var/lib/libvirt/quemu/name_of_virtual_machine.xml` I set the separate MAC of the virtual machine.

`networkctl status -a` on the virtual machine:

[image: screenshot]

Does anybody know why I can't get a connection to/from the VM by internet? I can ping the hosts IP from the VM but not a server in the internet.

Comment: Isn't that just right, from a Hosts POV this device is unmanaged - just as before networkd/netplan the host on a vnet device had nothing to do either.
Does the device come up from the guests POV?
What would you expect instead I assume something like 'n/a (unmanaged)' ?

Comment: I compared vnet0 with another server of mine (16.04 with /etc/network/interfaces) by "ip a" and there's no difference. So vnet0 should'nt be the problem I think.

Comment: Did you find a solution to that? Having the same problem.

Comment: No, not until now. For the mean time I deactivated netplan and switched back to /etc/network/interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to enable Promiscuous mode on the VSwitch. You can add another networking, enable promiscuous mode on that switch and connect guest to that switch.

Comment: VMware configuration Networking security settings promiscuous mode yes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that guest VM can only reach host machine but not any other machine on the network. Running `sudo iptables -vL` showed that the `FORWARD` policy was `DROP`, so I added an `ACCEPT` rule by `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p all -i br0 -j ACCEPT`. After that my guest VM became visible to the rest of the network. I used `iptables-persistent` to keep the settings around between reboots.